# I am trying to use the flutter ar_core_plugin but its not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, augmented-reality, arcore, flutter-plugin

I tried using the flutter ar_core_plugin and i have done everything that is required but its still giving me this error

```
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianm
arco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'ArCoreViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract ba
se class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.Platfo
rmViewFactory
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianm
arco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreViewFactory.kt: (14, 5): 'create' overrides nothing
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.11\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianm
arco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArcoreFlutterPlugin.kt: (32, 74): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':arcore_flutter_plugin:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             11.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried everything but couldnt get this plugin working

Comment: "I tried everything". Could you be more specific?

Comment: I installed the AR core and made the required changes to the build gradle file and the Android manifest.xml file too but its still not working